Column 2 value displaying below column 1 value when there is only one entry in the Combobox
I have created a 2-Column Combobox within a vba userform, the options the combobox is populated with are dependent on selections made by the user in previous comboboxes within the form.
The Combobox is populated from the Key and Item values stored in a vba dictionary.
The Combobox works perfectly if there are multiple options, but if there is only one option, then the combobox displays the second column value below the first column value like it is a different option. Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?
Apologies I am still quite new to VBA coding and am probably missing something very simple.
I've included a image to demonstrate the issue. The Combobox displays a position ID number in column 1 and the corresponding position Title in the second column.

Private Sub ComboBox5_DropButtonClick()
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = LBound(vList) To UBound(vList)
        If UCase(vList(i, 3)) = UCase(ComboBox1.Value) And _
            UCase(vList(i, 6)) = UCase(ComboBox2.Value) And _
            UCase(vList(i, 7)) = UCase(ComboBox3.Value) And _
            UCase(vList(i, 8)) = UCase(ComboBox4.Value) Then

            If Not d.Exists(vList(i, 1)) Then
                d.Add vList(i, 1), vList(i, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    Post = Application.Transpose(Array(d.keys, d.items))
    ComboBox5.ColumnCount = 2
    ComboBox5.List = Post
    d.RemoveAll
End Sub


Reposting my comment from staging: have you considered clearing the dictionary d before adding items?

"@timwilliams OMG I fixed it! Apparently if you only have one item to add to a ComboBox, then you need to add it using the addItem method, rather than the list method."

If you have only one item in your dictionary, you don't necessarily have to switch to the .AddItem method, you can also assign the post array as a whole - but this time via the boxe's transposing .Column property instead of .List. - See my late post +:;

Turns out you need to use a different method to populate the ComboBox if you only have ONE Item. .AddItem rather than .List
See my corrected code below, I hope it helps others who stumble across a similar issue.
Dim i As Long

d.RemoveAll
For i = LBound(vList) To UBound(vList)
    If UCase(vList(i, 3)) = UCase(ComboBox1.Value) _
        And UCase(vList(i, 6)) = UCase(ComboBox2.Value) _
        And UCase(vList(i, 7)) = UCase(ComboBox3.Value) _
        And UCase(vList(i, 8)) = UCase(ComboBox4.Value) Then
        If Not d.Exists(vList(i, 1)) Then
            d.Add vList(i, 1), vList(i, 2)
        End If
    End If
Next

ComboBox5.Clear
If d.Count = 1 Then
    With ComboBox5
        .AddItem d.Keys()(0)
        .Column(1, 0) = d.items()(0)
    End With
Else
    Post = Application.Transpose(Array(d.Keys, d.items))
    ComboBox5.ColumnCount = 2
    ComboBox5.List = Post
    d.RemoveAll
End If


Instead of writing Solved in your post you can now Accept Your Own Answers :)

If you have only one item in your dictionary, you don't necessarily have to switch to the .AddItem method, you can also assign the post array as a whole - but this time via the boxe's transposing .Column property instead of .List; you may wrap the relevant part also into a function with the combobox|listbox as argument (MSForms.Control) - see my late post :-)

Close to OP
Displaying only one item of your dictionary results to issues as Excel expects a 2dim array. By defining the unchanged Post array as shown in your original post first via
    Post= Application.Transpose(Array(d.keys, d.items))

and assigning it as 2dim-array back to the .Column property (instead of List)
    If d.Count = 1 Then                ' one item only
        Combobox5.Column = Post
    Else                               ' more items
        Combobox5.List = Post
    End If

you arrive to the wanted result and don't need to mix up methods.
